# Serre fibrations vs. Hurewicz fibrations

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, fibration

What is an example of a Serre fibration that is not a Hurewicz fibration?

Answer (score 5):

Let X be a mapping cylinder of the obvious map between the subspaces of the real line $\{n | n \in N\} \rightarrow {0}\cup\{1/n |n \in N^+\}$. Then the obvious map $X \rightarrow ({0}\cup\{1/n |n \in N^+\})\times I$ meets the requirement.

Denote $({0}\cup\{1/n |n \in N^+\})\times I$ by $Y$, and ${0}\cup\{1/n |n \in N^+\}$ by $Z$. So we have $f : X \rightarrow Y$.

Take the obvious map $k : Z \rightarrow X$. And an identity map $1_Y : Z\times I \rightarrow Y$ considered as a homotopy. Then the homotopy lifing fails.

On the other hand, it should not be hard to show that $f$ is a Serre fibration.

Comment: What should the codomain of that map be? Is it $\Bbb R$ or just the space $\{1/n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ ?

Comment: The codomain is $\{1/n| n \in \mathbb{N}\}\times I$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the codomain of the first map you mention in your answer.

Comment: The codomain is {1/n|n∈N} and the comain is {n|n∈N}. Basically, you take the set of natural numbers with the discrete topology and the set of natural numbers with the topology of {1/n|n∈N}. Then you pair up their point and connect each of those pairs by lines. And that's X.

Comment: But the topology on $\{1/n\mid n\in N\}$ is the discrete, isn't it?

Comment: oh, I mean that set plus 0, which is an accumulation point.

Comment: I see. So you have an injection $X\to(\{0\}\cup\{1/n\mid n\in N\})\times I$ which is not an embedding since the topology on the mapping cylinder $X$ is finer than the product topology. This $X$ is similar to the Arens-space. Thanks for clarifying. I think you should edit your answer to add the point $0$ to your set.

Comment: So you say this is not a fibration but a Serre fibration ... I will think about this. I'm currently studying different model structures on the category of topological spaces, and these structures differ by the type of fibrations that are involved, so this interests me :-)

Comment: Are you sure this is a Serre fibration? A path $h:I\to\{0\}\times I,h(t)=(0,t)$ does not have a lift in $X$.

Comment: Why? The lifting will also be $I \rightarrow {0}\times I, h(t)=(0,t)$.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your mapping. Does your $N$ contain $0$ ?

Comment: It does, I use $N$ for natural numbers and $N^+$ for positive naturals.

Comment: And your mapping sends $0$ to $0$ and $n\ge1$ to $1/n$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is right

Comment: Oh, then I see my mistake.

Comment: Ah, I understand why this is not a fibration. But it is a Serre fibration. In fact it has the HLP with respect to all connected spaces :-)